# select count of cities having population greater than 410000

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

i am new to sql . i have in a table data like

```
district    city    state   population
d1          c1       s1      2000
d2          c1       s1      10000
d3          c1       s1      400000
d1          c2       s2      500000
```

I want to have count of cities having population greater than 410000

so my desired output should be 2 as there are two cities c1 and c2. I want to first do group by on city and then calculate sum of population for each city and then check if its population is greater than 410000
so I have used the query

```
select count(city) from city_table group by city having sum(population) > 410000;
```

but output that i am getting is

```
count(city)
3
1
```

please tell what is wrong in my query

Answer (score 2):

You should use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select city, sum(population) as population
      from city_tabl
      group by city
      having sum(population) > 410000
     ) c;
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL query

```
select count(Distinct(city)) from city_table where population > 410000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help in MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(POPULATION) FROM CITY WHERE POPULATION > 410000;
```

Comment: The syntax is not correct